# C++ "noskipws" is not working as expected, How to properly allow whitespace in string?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to type in a full string, including white spaces, and then print that string.

Why is this code not behaving as I would expect?

**Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your name:\n";
    string name;
    cin >> noskipws >> name;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
 Enter your name:
>tes test test
 Hello, tes!
```

Comment: `std::noskipws` disables skipping of leading whitespace only.

Comment: @0x499602D2 What should I be using, then?

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, name)`

Comment: Newlines are  whitespace too so it's not clear how your proposal would stop reading

Comment: @M.M at the end of the string..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) stops the stream from skipping leading whitespace *before* it reads a value. [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will still stop reading when it reaches whitespace *after* a word.

If you want to read a whole line from the console, use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `operator>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your name:\n";
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper class to give yourself something that looks like an manipulator, if that is the syntax you want to use.

```
struct Getline {
    std::string &s_;
    Getline(std::string &s) : s_(s) {}
    friend auto & operator >> (std::istream &&is, Getline &&g) {
        return std::getline(is, g.s_);
    }
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your name:\n";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> Getline(name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!";
    return 0;

}
```